# Response code: 503 Response message: Service Unavailable

Tags: jmeter

I have given two url in csv file and trying to load that in jmeter. I am getting 503 response code.

[image]

Comment: What do server logs say?

Comment: I am very new to Jmeter. I dont know where server log is ? can you help me with that /

Comment: I'm just grabbing my crystal ball and try to solve the mystery. Really, read the logs of your server. 503 means: "The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state."

Answer (score 1):

As per [HTTP 503 status code description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503)

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 503 Service Unavailable server error response code indicates that the server is not ready to handle the request.
>
> Common causes are a server that is down for maintenance or that is overloaded. This response should be used for temporary conditions and the [Retry-After](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Retry-After) HTTP header should, if possible, contain the estimated time for the recovery of the service.
>
> ```
> Note: together with this response, a user-friendly page explaining the problem should be sent.
> ```
>
> Caching-related headers that are sent along with this response should be taken care of, as a 503 status is often a temporary condition and responses shouldn't usually be cached.

So I can think of at least 3 possible issues:

1. Your server is really overloaded, you can try checking `Response Data` tab of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener - if you're lucky - you will the the aforementioned "user-friendly page explaining the problem"
2. Your request is malformed and server is sending 503 response instead of [4xx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) which indicates client-side error. Double check what URL(s) you're trying to open by looking into `Request` tab of the View Results Tree listener and try to open it in the browser. If you're building the URL from parts (i.e. host, port, protocol, query string, etc.) - you might want to check if the values are correctly read from the CSV file using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)
3. I fail to see [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) in your Test Plan, some servers check the client [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), for example [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) or [Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) and may report an error if the required header is missing (i.e. indicating that the browser is not supported)